# Question involving Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\left \{ a_n \right \}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and $\left \{ x_n \right \}$ is a sequence with a number $k>0$ such that $|x_n - x_m|\leq k|a_n - a_m|$ for all $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$. Is $\left\{ x_n \right\}$ necessarily a Cauchy sequence? Either prove or give a counter-example.

My attempt: I think the question is true. So since $\left \{ a_n \right \}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then for $\forall \epsilon >0$, there is an $N$ so that for all $n,m>N$ $|a_n - a_m| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{k} $.

So for any $n,m$, we get $|x_n - x_m|<\epsilon \Rightarrow |x_n - x_m|\leq k|a_n - a_m|$.

Is that it to the proof? Looks quite simple to me.

Comment: Did you mean to say that there is a number $k>0$ such that $|x_{n}-x_{m}|\leq k|a_{n}-a_{m}|$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$?  If so your proof is almost correct -- you just need to switch the direction of the last implication.  That is, for any $n,m\geq N$ we have $|x_{n}-x_{m}|\leq k|a_{n}-a_{m}|\Rightarrow |x_{n}-x_{m}|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Simple facts have simple proofs.

Comment: So is {$x_n$} necessarily a Cauchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's right. The fact that $|a_n-a_m| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{k}$ is important: by transitivity, we then have $|x_n - x_m| \leq |a_n - a_m | \leq \frac{\epsilon}{k}$, so $|x_n - x_m| \le \epsilon$.